# Using prefix with string literal split over multiple lines

Tags: c++, multiline, prefix, string-literals

I have a Unicode string literal, let's say like this.

```cpp
const char8_t x[] = u8"aaa\nbbb©\nccc\n";
```

I would like to split it over multiple lines for readability.

Which of the notations below are correct and equivalent to the one above?

```cpp
const char8_t x[] =
        u8"aaa\n"
        u8"bbb©\n"
        u8"ccc\n";
```

```cpp
const char8_t x[] =
        u8"aaa\n"
        "bbb©\n"
        "ccc\n";
```

```cpp
const char8_t x[] =
        "aaa\n"
        u8"bbb©\n"
        "ccc\n";
```

All seem to compile but I'm afraid some of them may be implementation-defined.

Comment: Obviously, you won't use the third one as it is less readable.

Comment: If you want readability, then why are you not using raw string litterals? See#6 : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal.

Comment: @Phil1970 Wouldn't that mean I'd have to give up on indentation?

Comment: Well, it depend what you do with the data. If you write SQL, HTML, XML or similar, you might not necessarily care about extra indentation or you might fix it by code or you might prefer unindented text without `"` and `\n`. Also, one can probably write a `constexpr` function or operator that would fix the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), it would appear that all your code snippets are equivalent and well-defined:

> ##### Concatenation
>
> …
> If one of the strings has an encoding prefix and the other doesn't, the one that doesn't will be considered to have the same encoding prefix as the other.

Or, from [this Draft C++17 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf):

> ##### 5.13.5 String literals      [lex.string]
>
> …
> <sup>13</sup>      In translation phase 6 (5.2), adjacent *string-literals* are concatenated. If both *string-literals* have the same *encoding-prefix*, the resulting concatenated string literal has that *encoding-prefix*. If one *string-literal* has no *encoding-prefix*, it is treated as a *string-literal* of the same *encoding-prefix* as the other operand. …

Comment: [Link to the online Draft Standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.string#7).

Comment: Well, that's the theory. In practice, I would encourage to put the prefix at least in each line that has Unicode characters, unless you want to spend a few hours on debuggin why your code doesn't work in MSVC.

Answer (score 1):

You could use raw string literals here:

```
const char8_t x[]  =
u8R"(aaa
bbb©
ccc
)";
```

You don't need to explicitly state newline characters. The indentation is kept.
Here is an example with indentation:

```
const char8_t x[] =
u8R"(SomeRecord
    Name: $NAME
    Date: $DATE
)";
```

Comment: @NO_NAME I added indentation to the example.

Comment: @NO_NAME I reverted the original indentation but added an indented example.